# Where could I learn to edit page in magento 2?

Tags: magento2, theme, frontend, custom-theme

I'm new in magento 2 and I would like to learn how to edit for example any pages (front.end) in magento 2:

Mysite.com/page1
Mysite.com/page2 ecc ecc

I'm studing from the doc of magento 2 (front-end) but are there other free resources? I have a new theme with parent Luma, but I would like to understend beeter all the system of layout, block and fallback of magento

Comment: you want to explain CMS pages ??

Answer (score 0):

is the official documentation not enough https://devdocs.magento.com/#/individual-contributors ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to go through the official documents of the Magento or you should ask relevant questions about what you are actually facing. Hope you understand.